# facebook displays page instead of image and text in share box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's my share code.

```
$(document).ready(function (id) {
        $(".fbShare").on('click', function () {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: '@Model.Title',
                link: 'https://www.facebook.com/[PAGEID]/?sk=app_[APPID]&app_data=' + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                picture: 'http://i.imgur.com/V766ff5.jpg',
                caption: '',
                description: '@Model.StoryText'
            }, function (response) { });
        });
    });
```

But when I click to share it displays that
[image]

But I want to display there image, title and description. After share it's ugly too.. How can I solve that?

Same result is for fb like box where I have share

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/[PAGEID]/?sk=app_[APPID]&app_data=7" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params – pay attention to the introductory paragraph in the “Parameters” section.